# finite transcendence degree but not finitely generated field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $K\subset L$ be field extension such that transcendence degree tr.deg $L/K<\infty$.

Now, can we say $L/K$ is  finitely generated field extension?

Please tell me proof or contradiction, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for example the algebraic closure $L$ of $\Bbb Q$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$, hence $L/\Bbb Q$ has transcendence degree $0$ but it cannot be finitely generated as it is an infinite algebraic extension.

Comment: Nice example. The next interesting thing would be how the answer changes for purely transcendental extensions.

Comment: A purely transcendental extension of finite transcendence degree is finitely generated more or less by definition (i.e. there are algebraically independent elements $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ such that $L=K((x_i)_{i\in I})$ and as the transcendence degree is well-defined $I$ is finite)